# Bluemixのチームメンバー登録について

Tags: bluemix

チームで開発するため組織に他のユーザーを招待したり権限を設定したりする場合、BluemixのWeb UIからしか操作できないのでしょうか。APIやコマンドで多数のユーザーをまとめて管理できたりすると便利なのですが。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

確かにそのような機能があると便利ですね。
BluemixのベースであるCloud Foundryでは、cfコマンドの`create-user`でユーザーの追加、`set-org-role`, `set-space-role`でロールの設定を行えます。 しかしBluemixではこれら管理コマンドの権限を開放していないようで、Cloud Foundry CLIでこれらのコマンドを実行するとエラーになってしまいます。
現時点ではBluemixのWeb UIから設定するしかないようです。今後の拡張に期待。